# Create Virtual Device for Android L Developer Preview

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to start development with android L Developer Preview. First, I should create AVD, but I can't create AVD on Mac OS. I follow instruction on this link: https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html but it doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: What part doesn't work and how does it go wrong?

Comment: http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-install-android-l-sdk-windows-mac-1454737

Comment: I create virtual device based on instructions in above link, but after create virtual device successfully, it doesn't start and show a black screen! Nothing happened !

Answer (score 2):

The following configurations helped me created an Android L emulator successfully :

Device : Nexus 5

Target : Android L preview ( Ensure API 20 packages are installed as outlined in answers above )

CPU/ABI : Intel Atom x86

Skin WQVGA400

RAM : 2048 VM Heap : 64

Emulation options Snapshots , Use host GPU unchecked .

The emulator took a while to load but was successful ultimately.

Alternatively , if you have a Nexus 5 / 7 device to spare , try flashing the L preview system image on it following the steps outlined here : https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

You are assured of getting a wholesome( almost perfect ) Android L experience :)

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should install Android L Preview in Android SDK.
After, you cwill be able to enter AVD and create virtual device , for example, Nexus 5, with Android L. It might to have Name and RAM not bigger than your AVD alows. After setting your own settings, just try to start you AVD. It can take some time. Enjoy your coding!